What is Repository Model Service Controller classes and how to depends each other
I have worked multiple back-ends projects and develop multiple APIs which is used different different terms in the back-ends concepts can but I'm little bit confused about these terms - **Services, Repository, Models, controllers
can you clarify these terms what is  Repository Model Service Controller ?
what is main difference between these?
and last one How its depends on each other? Using the real life examples.

Model - Your data class
Repository - Some interface for the database queries that return/accept your Model
Service - A client that wraps some implementation of the Repository, for a specific database connection
Controller - In Java/Spring terms, this is what handles your HTTP requests and would use the Service
